# How to send an HTML file with css?

Tags: html, css

I have an html file which is linked to a CSS stylesheet and it is saved into my USB. I send it to a compressed folder and sent it via facebook to my friend, but when he opened it, the design in the first page is not loaded and the following pages cannot be displayed whereas here in my pc, it's working. It seems like it cannot locate the files and I think that it has something to do with the links and directories...
How am I going to send it so that my friend will be able to open it and see it in the same way?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is the html and css file in safe folder? can you share the link tag you are using in the html to link the css

Comment: yes sir they're in the same folder. this is the link: <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "/Networking Assign/style.css"  type ="text/css" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's in a compressed folder, your friend will need to extract the folder for each file to be able to use eachother.
Or, if your friend isn't that tech-savvy, you could inline all the css (i.e. not link to it externally) and JavaScript into one `.html` file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       /* All your styles here */
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>HTML here</h1>
      <script>
        //Some js code...
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sir I have already link it to an external styleheet and my friend had extracted it but still not working.

Comment: Oh, perhaps he has extracted it to a different location to that hich the html file links, i.e. if you have used a relative link (rel="/style.css") not an absolute link (rel="http://www.css.com/style.css", or "C:/Styles/style.css"). If you send me the files I will have a look at them if you want, otherwise it's a bit difficult to guess what's going on

Comment: so should I use an absolute link instead of relative link?

Comment: Well no, I was just sayig that that could be part of the problem; if the place your friend had extracted the css file to was *different* to the file linked to by the html file. Could you give us the line of code that links to your css file? *(e.g. something like `<link rel="stylesheet" rel="something/style.css">`)*

Comment: <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "/Networking Assign/style.css" type ="text/css" />

Comment: Ok, so in order for that to work, your friend must have a folder called `Networking Assign`, in which is a file called style.css. What is the highest level folder you have sent him? e.g. the first folder he is in, for example if you sent him a folder called HTML, and in that was the networking assign folder, the highest folder would be the HTML. and also, where is his index.html file located?

Comment: I have compressed the Networking Assign folder which contains all the htmk files and css and that's what I have sent to him. sorry but i don't know what index.html is.